# Android Studio/Android Monitor emulator 5554-is disconnected/offline/No connected devices

Tags: java, android-studio

When I click Android Studio, Open a project and then click Android Monitor the Monitor/logcat says that the emulator-5554 is offline/diconnected. SOmetimes there stands "No connected devices".

I uninstalled and intsalled Android Studio. I tried to wipe the data of the emulator. I deleted the emulator and installed it again. I trie in tools the SDK manager installing something but it failed. I tried in Settings of Android Studio switching off Instant run but nothing. I tried giving in the Terminal adb devices but it say that it can`t find them or any commands i give in it cant find. This is for a Course named Android and Developer course and i first noticed this when I tried activating the code and the emulator.

```
06/15 15:01:32: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\Dayan\Downloads\AnSt\02.05\DemoApp\app\build        \outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.robpercival.demoapp
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.robpercival.demoapp"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.robpercival.demoapp
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]


$ adb shell pm uninstall com.robpercival.demoapp
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR 
Error while Installing APK
```

Event Log
    14:49:38 Gradle sync started
    14:49:52 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
    14:49:52 * daemon started successfully
    14:50:44 Gradle sync completed
    14:50:44 Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies,   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
    14:50:55 Gradle build finished in 10s 710ms
    15:01:02 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
    15:01:30 Gradle build finished in 28s 681ms
    15:02:24 Session 'app': Error Installing APK

```
C:\Users\Dayan\Downloads\AnSt\02.05\DemoApp>adb devices
Der Befehl "adb" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

I expected in logcat to see Username: .......... and Password:..........
But now i dont see anything only a ery long text in logcat which i cant understand